# Https params angular 7 error 404 Not Found

Tags: angular, http, parameters, header, angular-httpclient

What did I miss here? Not getting back the right URL, the lat long is not correctly displayed and I get an 404 not found error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as constants from '../../src/app/constants/constants';



@Injectable()


export class ForecastService {

   url = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${constants.DARKSKY_API_KEY}/`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  getForecastData(lat: number, lng: number): Observable<any>  {
    let params = new HttpParams()
    params = params.set('lat', lat.toString() )
    params = params.set('lng', lng.toString() )
    console.log(lat,lng)

    return this.http.get(this.url, {params:params})


  }
}
```

what i get back is the error:
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.da…2823eaa6089/?lat=52.025137099999995&lng=5.0709602" –

Comment: Please review api URL..!

Comment: review constants path

Comment: the url comes back ok, it looks like the params aren't getting back correct?

Comment: URL contains two host names. Please check

Comment: 404 error that mean URL not correct

Comment: Check if your constant has the `DARKSKY_API_KEY` and the path is correctly assigned, put a breakpoint in return http.get and check if it's returning correctly here !

Comment: Try this instead url =`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${constants.DARKSKY_API_KEY}`

Comment: If i let the first part out, i get a cors error

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.da…2823eaa6089/?lat=52.025137099999995&lng=5.0709602"